# Redirect to webpage while click on OK Button using DialogPreference

Tags: android

I am using DialogPreference in my program, now i want to **Redirect to webpage while click on OK Button** using DialogPreference.

*Preferences.xml:-*

```
   <com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.contacts.TimePickerPreferences
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:key="about"
    android:summary="Summary"
    android:title="Title"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null" />
```

*TimePickerPreferences.java:-*

```
      public class TimePickerPreferences extends DialogPreference
  {
public TimePickerPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public TimePickerPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                      int button) {
    if (button == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) 
    {Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(myWebLink);
    }
}
```